# Can't get value from Dictionary like object in JS

Tags: javascript

I have the following object:

[image: a list of objects in JS]

Having the name of the county, I want to quickly get the population.So with a bit of code I got [from here](http://bit.ly/1yXLL2U), I want to be able to quickly get the population of each county (the number bit). So I try to do this:

```
var lookup = {};
var len    = cdata.length;
var i;
for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    lookup[cdata[i].county.replace(/ /g,'').toLowerCase()] = cdata[i].count;
}
```

My lookup object is now this:

```
Object {devon: "747900", suffolk: "730100", westyorkshire: "2227400", kent: "1466500", lancashire: "171600"}
```

Then when I try to obtain the population number like so:

```
lookup[devon]
```

I get the following **error**:

> Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function

Why isn't the above working? Also is that the best way to quickly get at the population I need?

Comment: Are you sure? Because `lookup(devon)` is not the same as `lookup[devon]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to address to object properties like this:

`lookup["devon"]` or `lookup.devon`